# Search filter in Xamarin Listview not showing in view

Tags: listview, xamarin, search, mvvm, searchbar

## Error while displaying in the list

I have an error at the time of showing in the view the query to the api is generated correctly but at the time of listing they are not shown in the view. As it appears in the screenshot, it does not show any results.

**Vista**
`

```
 <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <ViewModels:ComidaViewModel>
        </ViewModels:ComidaViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>
        <SearchBar Placeholder="Busca tu alimento por categoria"
                   x:Name="search"
                   SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCommand}"
                   SearchCommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference search}}"></SearchBar>
        <ListView
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            RowHeight="250">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Frame CornerRadius="5"
                               Margin="5"
                               BackgroundColor="Red">
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Image Source="{Binding urlImg}" HeightRequest="100"></Image>
                                <Label Text="{Binding nombreAlimento}"></Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

`
**View Model**
`

```
 ApiRest apiRest = new ApiRest();
        public ObservableCollection<ComidaModel> Items { get; set; }
        public string categoriaAlimento { get; set; }
        public ICommand SearchCommand { get; set; }


        public ComidaViewModel()
        {
            try
            {
                SearchCommand =
               new Command(async (text) =>
               {
                   try
                   {

                       string response = "";
                       Task.Run(async () =>
                       {
                           response = await apiRest.ConsultaAlimentos(text.ToString());
                       }).Wait();
                       List<ComidaModel> consulta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ComidaModel>>(response);
                       Items = new ObservableCollection<ComidaModel>();
                       foreach (ComidaModel consultas in consulta)
                       {
                           Items.Add(consultas);
                       }
                   }
                   catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine(ex);
                   }


               });



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

        }

    }
```

`

## I expected the list to be displayed with the filter

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted, I found you didn't define any view in the `ViewCell` of the `ListView` and bind the relative property of model `ComidaModel` of datasource `Items` .

```
   Items = new ObservableCollection<ComidaModel>();
```

You can refer to the following code:

```
  <ListView  x:Name="lstView" RowHeight="60">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
        <!--  add your control here and bind the property of your item ComidaModel  -->
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="Olive">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Label Text = "{Binding Name}" FontSize="24" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.25, 0.25, 400, 40"/>
                                <Label Text = "{Binding Type}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="50, 35, 200, 25"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" HorizontalOptions="End" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="250.25, 0.25, 50, 50 "/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

For more information, you can check document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance .

**Update 1:**

> Follow the same error does not show any results does not show the list

For the problem, please try to initialize variable  `Items`  in the constructor of viewmodel `ComidaViewModel` instead of initializing in the `SearchCommand` .

Please refer to the following code:

```
 public ComidaViewModel() 
        {
            consulta = new List<ComidaModel>();

            //initialize variable  `Items ` here 
            Items = new ObservableCollection<ComidaModel>();

            try
            {
                SearchCommand =
               new Command(async (text) =>
               {
                   try
                   {
                       // other code

                       // remove code here
                       //Items = new ObservableCollection<ComidaModel>();
                       foreach (ComidaModel consultas in consulta)
                       {
                           Items.Add(consultas);
                       }
                   }
                   catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine(ex);
                   }


               });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
```

**Update 2**

Based on your code, I created a demo and simulated this function.
I added several functions：

1.add the Initial data

2.add the filter function `GetSearchResults`

You can refer to the following code:

ComidaViewModel.cs

```
public class ComidaViewModel 
{
    public ObservableCollection<ComidaModel> Items { get; set; }

    public List<ComidaModel> consulta { get; set; }
    public string categoriaAlimento { get; set; }

    public ICommand SearchCommand { get; set; }


    public  List<ComidaModel> GetSearchResults(string queryString)
    {
        var normalizedQuery = queryString?.ToLower() ?? "";
        return consulta.Where(f => f.nombreAlimento.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(normalizedQuery)).ToList();
    }

    public ComidaViewModel()
    {
        consulta = new List<ComidaModel>();

        //  you can init data here
        consulta.Add(new ComidaModel { urlImg = "cherry.png", nombreAlimento = "test1" });
        consulta.Add(new ComidaModel { urlImg = "grass.png", nombreAlimento = "abc2" });
        consulta.Add(new ComidaModel { urlImg = "cherry.png", nombreAlimento = "abd3" });
        consulta.Add(new ComidaModel { urlImg = "grass.png", nombreAlimento = "def4" });
        consulta.Add(new ComidaModel { urlImg = "cherry.png", nombreAlimento = "fgh5" });
        consulta.Add(new ComidaModel { urlImg = "grass.png", nombreAlimento = "jkl6" });
        consulta.Add(new ComidaModel { urlImg = "cherry.png", nombreAlimento = "test7" });

        Items = new ObservableCollection<ComidaModel>(consulta);

        //Items = new ObservableCollection<ComidaModel>();

        try
        {
            SearchCommand =
           new Command<string>(async (text) =>
           {
               try
               {
                   List<ComidaModel> data = new List<ComidaModel>();

                   data = GetSearchResults(text);

                   Items.Clear();
                   foreach (ComidaModel model in data)
                   {
                       Items.Add(model);
                   }

               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(ex);
               }
           });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

ComidaModel.cs

```
public class ComidaModel 
{
    public string urlImg { get; set; }
    public string nombreAlimento { get; set; }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:formlistviewapp="clr-namespace:FormListViewApp"
             x:Class="FormListViewApp.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <formlistviewapp:ComidaViewModel></formlistviewapp:ComidaViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>
        <SearchBar Placeholder=""
                   x:Name="search"
                   SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCommand}"
                   SearchCommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference search}}"></SearchBar>
        <ListView
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            RowHeight="100">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Frame CornerRadius="5"
                               Margin="5"
                               BackgroundColor="Yellow">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="{Binding urlImg}" HeightRequest="30"></Image>
                                <Label Text="{Binding nombreAlimento}"></Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Follow the same error does not show any results does not show the list

Comment: Hi @IsaacGamalielMuñiz,I have updated my answer. You can check the updated part.

Comment: If the problem persists, could you please post the latest codes so that I can help you better?

Comment: Did you press the search button after typing?  Event `SearchCommand` will only been triggered by pressing `Search` button.